# A quantum particle which is almost at rest but whose position is random!

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Assume a particle is given by a quantum state which is constructed in such a way that it is equally probable to find it anywhere in an fixed interval $(0,L)$ but has arbitrarily low velocity. The particle is almost at rest but its position is still random!

I will give a construction for such a quantum state. Let

$$\psi(x) = B(x)e^{ikx},$$

where $B(x)$ is a [function with smooth cut off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) which is almost like a square function which is $1$ in $(0,L)$ and zero everywhere else. ( I have introduced $B(x)$ over square function to eliminate arguments about continuity of $\psi(x)$).

The most probable momentum of this particle is $k$ with a manageble uncertainty. If we fix $L$ to be at certain high value, then the uncertainty in momentum is fixed at a low value.

Now the question is, in the above set up we can choose $k$ to be arbitrarily small and with almost same low uncertainty and still have its position equally distributed in an entire interval $(0,L)$.

In essence we have a valid quantum state in which a particle is almost at rest, but whose position is totally random in an interval. Although I am new to quantum mechanics, I find this very intriguing and almost hard to imagine such a real world situation. Is this a possible flaw with in QM? I'd appreciate your comments and explanation of any pitfalls in this argument.

Comment: @Qmechanic : The uncertainity principle does not directly impose the position probability distribution to be specifically uniformly distributed in in $(0,L)$. There could be many other distribution which yield same uncertainity in position and are more intuitively appealing. Uniform distribution is something totally random.

Comment: @Michael Brown : ^^

Comment: You actually can't make $k$ arbitrarily small. There is a zero energy limited by the size where your particle is constraint to be. Or in different terms, for physically plausible wave functions constrained in (0,L), the wave function must go to zero at the borders, thus $k_{min} = 2\pi / L$.

Comment: Hi Rajesh. My comment is just a simplified restatement of Qmechanic answer, perhaps clearer for a starting student. But if you want to accept an answer I guess it should be his.

Comment: @perplexity : How? Qmechanic never said $k$ cannot be arbitrarily small.

Comment: He gave you the correct answer (see point ii). The wave vector in $\exp(ikx)$ can actually be zero, meaning equal probability of moving left/right ($\langle \psi |\hat{p}|\psi \rangle = 0$) but because $B(x)$ is constrained between $0$ and $L$, its Fourier Transform imposes a minimum uncertainty $\Delta k$ that forbids the kinetic energy to be zero, and hence the particle to be at rest.

Answer (score 4):

I) A [mollifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) $B$ times a [plane wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave) $e^{ikx}$ is an example of a smooth wave packet $\psi\in {\cal H}=L^2(\mathbb{R})$. The [Heisenberg uncertainty relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) is a mathematical consequence of the [CCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation), and holds in particular for the above mentioned wave packet $\psi$.

II) Intuitively, the expectation value

$$\langle \hat{p}\rangle~=~\frac{\langle \psi |\hat{p}|\psi\rangle}{\langle \psi|\psi\rangle}$$

of the momentum operator is roughly the bare plane wave momentum $\hbar k$; and the slowly varying mollifier $B$ unavoidably creates a possible small, but strictly non-zero uncertainty/fuzziness

$${\rm Var}(\hat{p})~=~\frac{\langle \psi |(\hat{p}-\langle \hat{p}\rangle)^2|\psi\rangle}{\langle \psi|\psi\rangle}~>~0$$

in the momentum; independently of the value of the plane wave wavenumber $k$.

III) If the reader is unconvinced by the above arguments, then it is a good educational exercise to replace the mollifier $B$ by a slowly varying [Gaussian function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function), and explicitly calculate how everything works out.

Comment: +1. thanks for the clear explanation, it really adds a lot of value to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic consequence of the uncertainty principle which is not only not a possible flaw with QM, it is an experimental fact. You can observe this pretty much directly in Bose-Einstein condensates of ultracold atoms, for instance. Conversely, the confinement pressure is essential to the stability of atoms as you will find out in your QM course. It has been verified in a thousand other ways as well. It even has budgetary consequences: it is the reason why the LHC has to be so big to find things like the Higgs boson which can only been seen at very short distance scales.